# invoke bridge.net compiler at runtime

Tags: c#, bridge.net

I am designing an application that will need to create some C# classes at runtime.  I would like to be able to convert those classes into javascript equivalents.  For example I might have a C# class that looks like

```
public class Person
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public bool IsScoreValid()
    {//code in real implementation would be more complex and make use of various properties
        return Score > 0 && Score <= 100;
    }
}
```

The trick here is that the Person class here will be created at runtime based on some configuration.  I do not have control over the code in the IsScoreValid method and it could change while the application is running.  I only know that it is valid C# code.  I need a robust way to convert this class into a javascript equivalent, and I need to be able to perform this conversion at runtime. Would Bridge.net be a good way to convert this javascript?  Can Bridge.net compiler be invoked at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is possible? It indeed is, see http://deck.net/. But unfortunately the project is not open source. Basically it is a project that directly calls Bridge.Translator.Translate() method with the right parameters to build the file.

A web project implementing real time bridge compilation would need to be capable of handling server-side calls, like webservices (ashx) in Asp.NET, but you can also do that via cgi-bin or php from linux/osx, using the Bridge CLI if you make commandline calls, or wire up a wrapper to call Bridge.Translator directly. That would need to be a Mono-capable binary to be linked against Bridge.Translator on Linux/osx though.

While the deck.net project is not open, Bridge itself is, so you have full access to see how to call Bridge's Translate() method from either the Bridge.Builder or Bridge CLI open projects.

- [Bridge Builder console app sources at Bridge main repository](https://github.com/bridgedotnet/Bridge/blob/master/Compiler/Builder/Program.cs)
- [Bridge Translator sources at Bridge main repository](https://github.com/bridgedotnet/Bridge/blob/master/Compiler/Translator/Translator/Translator.cs)
- [Bridge CLI sources](https://github.com/bridgedotnet/CLI/)

But if you want the code not to care about references, like missing the definition or a prototype for `IsScoreValid()`, then that would be a problem to work with Bridge. It would require at least the method to be prototyped and marked `External` before it could accept the call; as the code tree is built thru roslyn, the c# code must be complete and buildable. (or else, could we call it proper C#? maybe, in your case, you don't really require full-fledged C#)